# CakePHP: post data disappears after redirecting to login page

Tags: cakephp

When I test submitting my form (by the [post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) method) with a logged in user, it sends data correctly, but when I am not logged in, it redirects to the login page.

But this `if` statement in `beforeRender()` of app_controller.php returns false:

```
if ($this->RequestHandler->isPost())
```

In fact, `$this->data` is empty. Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you try explaining yourself a little better? I don't quite understand your issue

Comment: ok, when i click a button, javascript opens a popup and sends a post data to it (by submitting a on the fly form). so far everything is ok.  when user is not logged in, it will redirect to login page (in that popup). and i want to save form's post data into a session but post data is destroyed after redirect, but i think it should be alive according this post: [Post data again after authorization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177261/post-data-again-after-authorization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed. POST data cannot be retained through a redirect. The HTTP protocol simply doesn't allow for it* and CakePHP doesn't do anything to work around this limitation. The browser sends a POST request to the server, the server responds with a `302 Found` redirect with a `Location` header, the browser issues a GET request to the given `Location`. The browser does not send the POST data again.

See Stack Overflow question *[Post data again after authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177261/post-data-again-after-authorization)* for a manual workaround.

<sub>* HTTP allows it using a `307 Temporary Redirect`, but no browser seems to implement this correctly.</sub>

Comment: i am confused, what is the difference between my question and that question (Post data again after authorization)? i have the same problem!  (sorry, my english in not very good)

Comment: The difference is that you're asking what the problem is, while the linked question asks what the solution is. I answered accordingly. :)

Comment: i really don't understand the difference :( i just want to send data to server while users login, or even save data to a <input> for sending again after login

Comment: Then read the [answer I linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177261/post-data-again-after-authorization), that should get you going.

Comment: that's only a session write and session read. my problem is missing post data. i want to """access""" data. how can i regain data to my <input> while i miss it?!

Comment: Plain and simple: The only way to persist POST data through a redirect is to save it somewhere **before** the redirect, then read it back after the redirect. How to do this using the session as storage is explained in the linked-to Q&A. The `$_POST` data is always gone, there's no way to keep it.